# Go back a page before a search takes place - URL doesn't change

Tags: javascript

I have a page that is built into a learning mgmt system where I can customize it via an HTML editor/WYSIWYG. When I put in this snippet:

```html
<input type="button" value="Go Back" onclick="history.go(-1);return true;">
```

it works to go back a page. However, when I perform a search, the URL doesn't change, so it goes back to the page before the "home search page". Is there something to allow it to go back before the search even though the URL is identical and can be used in the WYSIWYG?

Answer (score 0):

If the URL doesn't change when a search is performed, then the search is likely being done with ajax. Since the page isn't reloading, there's nothing you can do to make it go back as expected.

If you can keep track of the page's state, then you could call `location.reload()` instead of `history.go(-1)` if a search has been made. That'll reload the page to the search form.